# What happens if the Root name server gets down?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, tld

What happens if the [Root name server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_name_server) of a [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) gets down? Does it lead to the malfunction of domains with that domain extension?

Comment: The DNS root is not a TLD and a TLD is not the root. There are both nameservers for the root operated on a distributed basis, as Turdie answered, and _also_ highly-available nameservers for each TLD (`.com .net .org .gov .us .uk .fr .de .jp .cn` etc etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To guarantee availability as much as possible, there are 13 different addresses for the root servers, all of which are based on Anycast to increase availability even further. In essence, there are more than 1580 different servers spread across the world

This means, for example, that the K-Root server, which is managed by RIPE NCC, is actually located at 110 (reference date 14-02-2023) locations around the world. And at each location a cluster runs with the DNS server. K-Root uses the NSD Name Server Daemon. Some of these installations are global (available to everyone) and some local (only accessible from certain countries/networks).

Not really an answer, but they are extremely high available.